# Docker toolbox on windows 10 error make command not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, openwhisk

I want to install docker toolbox on my windows 10 home pc. Everything works perfectly but I want to install openwhisk with docker and I get error on the following commands

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-devtools.git
cd incubator-openwhisk-devtools/docker-compose
make quick-start
```

The error that I get is the following:

```
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The `incubator-openwhisk-devtools` project has not yet been ported to Windows. Unless you can find a unix-based environment to use, I'd suggest looking at the virtual machine based setup instructions instead: https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk#vagrant-setup